# How to identify edge date cases using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14],
                        'date_birth': ['12/31/1961','01/01/1961','10/21/1961','12/11/1961','02/11/1961',
                                       '05/29/1967','01/29/1967','04/29/1967','03/19/1967','01/01/1957', 
                                       '12/31/1959','01/01/1959','01/01/1959','07/27/1959',
                                       '01/01/1957','01/01/1957','12/31/1957','12/31/1958','01/01/1957']})
df1 = df1.melt('person_id', value_name='dates')
df1['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['dates'])
```

My objective is to identify the `edge cases` in this data frame.

An edge case is defined as a scenario when a subject has both `Jan 1st` and `Dec 31st` in their `dates` column.
For instance, from the sample data frame we can see that `person_id=11` is a edge case because he has both `Jan 1st` and `Dec 31st` in their `dates` column values whereas person_id = 12 is not a edge case because he doesn't have both `Dec 31st` and `Jan 1st`

This is what I tried

```
op_df = df1.groupby(['person_id'], sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['dates'], ascending=True)).reset_index(drop=True)
op_df['day'] = op_df.dates.dt.day
op_df['month'] = op_df.dates.dt.month
op_df['points'] = np.where(((op_df['day'] == 1) & (op_df['month'] == 1)) & ((op_df['day'] == 31) & (op_df['month'] == 12)),'edge','No')
```

But the code above doesn't filter correctly. It returns as `No` for all my person_ids.

I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is problem is not possible `day=1& month=1` with end of month, need chain by `|` for `OR`:

```
op_df = df1.sort_values(['person_id','dates'])
op_df['day'] = op_df.dates.dt.day
op_df['month'] = op_df.dates.dt.month
op_df['points'] = np.where(((op_df['day'] == 1) & (op_df['month'] == 1)) | ((op_df['day'] == 31) & (op_df['month'] == 12)),'edge','No')
```

If need for both edges separate columns is possible create 2 columns first by masks, aggregate `sum` for count `True`s values and add `Edge` column in [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) for second column by condition - `Yes` if at least one `0` in one or second column:

```
#instead groupby + sort_values use sort_values by 2 columns
op_df = df1.sort_values(['person_id','dates'], ascending=True)

day = op_df.dates.dt.day
month = op_df.dates.dt.month
   
op_df['1.1'] = (day == 1) & (month == 1)
op_df['31.12'] = (day == 31) & (month == 12)

op_df = op_df.groupby('person_id', as_index=False)[['1.1','31.12']].sum()
op_df.insert(1, 'Edge', np.where(op_df[['1.1','31.12']].eq(0).any(axis=1),'No','Yes'))
print (op_df)
   person_id Edge  1.1  31.12
0         11  Yes    1      1
1         12   No    1      0
2         13  Yes    2      1
3         14  Yes    3      2
```